# Netbeans 7.4 settings for javascript code within php

Tags: javascript, php, netbeans-7.4

I just installed the new version of netbeans and code within "`<script> </ script>`" not well indented appearance as in previous versions.

How could reconfigure it?

A greeting.

[image]

SOLVED: The problem was that had a plugins desactivate, i activated all and it recovery the normally.

Comment: Have you tried to restart IDE after this? There is an issue that happens only once - with fresh user dir (typically after new installation) which causes embedded JS to lose some coloring/formatting. After IDE restart, it should be OK

Comment: Thanks for you answer, yes, i tray to restart, but it doesnt work.

The problem was that had a plugins desactivate, i activated all and it recovery the normally.